# How to fire rules in a loop

Tags: drools

drools 7.x

this is a spring boot project, and the drools configuration is:

```
@Configuration
public class DroolsConfig {

    private static final String RULES_PATH = "rule/";

    @Bean
    public KieFileSystem kieFileSystem() throws IOException {
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = getKieServices().newKieFileSystem();
        for (Resource file : getRuleFiles()) {
            kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(RULES_PATH + file.getFilename(), "UTF-8"));
        }
        return kieFileSystem;
    }

    private Resource[] getRuleFiles() throws IOException {
        ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        return resourcePatternResolver.getResources("classpath*:" + RULES_PATH + "**/*.*");
    }

    @Bean
    public KieContainer kieContainer() throws IOException {
        final KieRepository kieRepository = getKieServices().getRepository();
        kieRepository.addKieModule(new KieModule() {
            public ReleaseId getReleaseId() {
                return kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId();
            }
        });
        KieBuilder kieBuilder = getKieServices().newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem());
        kieBuilder.buildAll();
        return getKieServices().newKieContainer(kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId());
    }

    private KieServices getKieServices() {
        return KieServices.Factory.get();
    }
}
```

java code is:

```
@Autowired
private KieContainer kieContainer;

public void test() {

        KieSession kSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();

        kSession.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("test").setFocus();

        for (int i=0;i<2;i++) {

            Model c = new Model();

            c.setName(String.valueOf(i));

            kSession.insert(c);
            kSession.fireAllRules();
        }//for

        kSession.dispose();

        return null;
    }
```

**the only dependency is `kie-ci 7.59.0.Final` in my maven pom file.**

drl file is in `src/main/resources/rule`:

```
package rule;

import com.my.b.Model;

agenda-group "test";

rule "1"
    when
        $c : Model(name == '0')
    then
        System.out.println("*****0");
end
rule "2"
    when
        $c : Model(name == '1')
    then
        System.out.println("*****1");
end
```

I run junit test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    void test() {
        
        this.myService.test();
    }
}
```

However, only `rule 1` is fired, `rul2` is not fired when insert and fire `Model` with name is 1? that is only `*****0` is printed in the idea console.

what is the problem?

Comment: Both rules activate for me for your scenario. You have some other code which causes the issue that is not listed. BTW up-votes is not the reason people help here, but they show that you care.

Comment: I mean ... this makes total sense. In the first version you have only one object in memory when you fire the rules so each time you fire them only one rule triggers. In the second version you have multiple object in memory so multiple rules trigger. I'm uncertain what you're actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Sorry, I removed the confused content. I mean why my code only fire `rule1` ? (it should be fire both `rule1` and `rule2` because the `for` iterate two times)

Comment: Are you intentionally reusing the same stateful session?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yes, my code looks like `KieSession k = kieContainer.newKieSession(); for(){ k.insert();k.fireAllRules();} k.dispose();`

Comment: Yes i see that i was wondering if it's intentional. Usually people don't reuse stateful sessions.

Comment: that is if i want to fire rules with stateful sessions in a loop, I have to create new stateful session each time in the loop? If that is the case, is there any disadvantage to create new stateful session in the loop?(e.g. performance problem)

Comment: Do you have a sample project showing this behavior? I would disagree with @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas about stateful sessions not being normally reused.

Comment: I'm always suspicious when I find that behavior because you need to understand a bit more about how drools works than if you were using stateless sessions. So possibly it would be better worded "usually people don't _correctly_ reuse stateful sessions". I've seen this a lot when doing consulting unfortunately.

Comment: 100% agree on that